# how many parameters can a vector have?

Tags: c++11

Until now I had only 1 thing in mind
`vector<int> vec(100)`  where 100 is the size of the vector.
But recently I saw like this
`vector<float> angle (3600, 0.)` and I don't understand what is the second parameter for?
Is it possible to have even more parameters for a vector in C++?

Comment: If all else fails, read the [manual](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).

Comment: "where 100 is the capacity": that's already wrong...

Comment: @MarcGlisse than what does it means?

Comment: @AlwaysMinus It sets the *size,* not the *capacity.*

Comment: @n.m. You mean read **a** manual, right? Or "a good manual".

Comment: @Angew yes, I meant size, but wrote capacity. Sorry for mistake.
But still don't know what do you want to point by "a good manual"?

Comment: @AlwaysMinus The point about "a" manual (or "a good" manual) instead of "the" manual was aimed at n.m., who linked to excellent C++ documentation (cppreference). I just wanted to point out that while cppreference is an excellent manual, it's not **the** manual in sense of officiality or canonicity; there's no such thing as an official C++ manual (except maybe the standard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in your case two parameters are like this,
1. size of the vector
2. value(s) to filled up
So in your case your vector `angle` is contains *0* for *3600* times.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor is heavily overloaded to allow for initialisation to a set value and for specialised memory management. Just navigate to the documentation and read the options.